# how to check if folder exist and create folder using python

Tags: python, directory

How to check if folder exist and create it if it doesn't?

```
import os
from datetime import datetime

file_path = "F:/TEST--"
if os.path.exists(file_path):
    os.rmdir(file_path)
    os.makedirs(file_path + datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
else:
    os.makedirs(file_path + datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
```

Comment: What's wrong with what you have?

Comment: it doesn't create the folder if already exist

Answer (score 0):

`os.path.exists(file_path)` check if the folder `TEST--` exists, not if `TEST--date` exists, so `os.rmdir(file_path)` is never called. Set the folder name before the `if`

```
file_path = 'F:/TEST--' + datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
if os.path.exists(file_path):
    os.rmdir(file_path)
os.makedirs(file_path)
```

If the folder contain files you need to delete the first or use `shutil` package

```
shutil.rmtree(file_path)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use exist_ok parameter set to True.then if folder exists.python will do nothing.

```py
import os
from datetime import datetime
file_path = "F:/TEST--"
if os.path.exists(file_path):
    os.rmdir(file_path)

os.makedirs(file_path + datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d'),exist_ok=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

On Python >= 3.5, you can use [pathlib.Path.mkdir](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.mkdir). Note the `exist_ok=True` parameter.

```
from pathlib import Path
from datetime import datetime

file_path = 'F:/TEST--' + datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
Path(file_path).mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
```

Using Pathlib makes your code OS independent and will not break if you decide to move to another OS later on.

PS: It is also advisable to avoid hardcoded paths in your code like `F:/TEST--`